# How to record statistics on the parsing of text files?

Tags: parsing, f#, statistics, yacc, lex

My company uses some kind of domain specific language and I am writing a parser for it, in F#, using FsLex and FsYacc. As the language has evolved over the years, it now has deprecated constructs that clutter the grammar of the language and part of my task is to clean it up.

To do so, I want to know what rules are used often and what rules are seldom used. I also want to keep track of what rules are used together, since I believe the language contains several "styles". I want to identify these different styles.

My idea was to keep track of all the rules that matched during parsing. That is, my parser does two things when matching a rule:

1. It builds the abstract syntax tree (as a normal parser).
2. It keeps track of rules that matched. To do so, I keep a hash table where keys are strings (the name of the rule), and values are the number of matches of the rule. Each time I match a rule, I increase the counter associated with the rule. This is done as a side effect of the parsing.

My problem is that I have to do two things at once for every rule, which clutters the code. Moreover, since I want to know what rules *did not match* during the parse, I need to keep a separated list of all the rules, a list that I will have to update manually each time I update the grammar. This list is probably going to contain errors after a couple of changes, so I was looking for a better solution.

Therefore, my question is: Is there a way to obtain statistics on which rules matched and which rules did not, directly from the parser (or in the FsYacc definition file)? Are there other tools that would permit this? Are there other ways to analyse how a language is used in practice?

**Note:** I also thought about using hidden Markov chains and the [Baum-Welch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baum%E2%80%93Welch_algorithmhttp://) to learn a parser out of the tokenized source code and try to compare it to my own parser. However, this might be a difficult task as I might need many states in the hidden markov model. I would also have to try to understand what the states actually mean, which might be difficult, particularly in case of overfitting. However, I would also be interested to get feedback if people tried this approach.

Thanks!